# Custom module administration page template not working

Tags: 7, theming

I've been trying to load a custom template for a custom module page in the administration section, but the template isn't being loaded. This is the code so far:

#### custom_theme.module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function module_custom_menu() {

    $template_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'module_custom') . '/templates';

    $items['admin/module-custom'] = array(
        'title' => 'Turnos',
        'description' => 'Custom module functionality',
        'position' => 'right',
        'weight' => -15,
        'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
        'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
        'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
        'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
    );

    $items['admin/module-custom/availability'] = array(
        'title' => 'Captación de disponibilidad',
        'description' => 'Users availability functionality',
        'page callback' => 'user_availabity',
        'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

    return $items;

}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 */
function module_custom_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

    $template_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'module_custom') . '/templates';

    return array(
        'user_availability' => array(
            'variables' => array('users', NULL),
            'template' => 'module-custom-admin',
            'path' => $template_path
        )
    );

}

/**
 * Load user availability
 */
function user_availabity() {

    $users = entity_load('user');    
    return theme('user_availabity', $users);

}
```

#### module-custom-admin.tpl.php

```
<div>
    <h2>Template subtitle</h2>
</div>
<div>
    <?php foreach ($users as $key => $user) : ?>
        <div>
            <?php print_r($user); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

But the template's code isn't shown:
[image: Module admin page]
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hook_theme` expect second parameter to be an array. See the doc [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7.x). In your implementation below you are passing an object.

```
/**
 * Load user availability
 */
function user_availabity() {

    $users = entity_load('user');    
    return theme('user_availabity', $users);

}
```

What you can do is to [typecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array) the value.

```
$users = (array) entity_load('user', array(uid));
```

Here is an example from my existing project.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function derusni_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'quotation_list' => array(
      'template' => 'quotation-list',
      'path' => $path . '/templates',
      'type' => 'theme',
      'variables' => array(),
    ),
  );
}
```

And here is function that implements that theme function.

```
/**
 * List the quotation started by user.
 */
function derusni_page_quotation_started() {
  $variables = array();

  $quotation_ids = _get_quotations(arg(1), 'Started');
  foreach ($quotation_ids as $quotation_id) {
    $variables['quotations'][] = entity_load_single('quotation', $quotation_id);
  }
  $variables['edit_path'] = "/admin/structure/entity-type/quotation/quotation/";
  $variables['dest_path'] = '?destination=/' . current_path();

  return theme('quotation_list', $variables);
}
```

HTH

Comment: @AndresMauricio please see my update with example

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried the same as your example and it worked.

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is a well known [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/342350) of the `hook_theme()` function.

For successfully loading the template file, you have to follow the naming convention to rename the template name, which must be same as the theme key, with converting `_` to `-`.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 */
function module_custom_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

    $template_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'module_custom') . '/templates';

    return array(
        'user_availability' => array(
            'variables' => array('users', NULL),
            'template' => 'user-availability',
            'path' => $template_path
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: Well, I tried as suggested in the link, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Did clear cache?

Comment: Yeah, I always do that after any change in the module's code.

Comment: How about you define the theme key with module name prefix? It is rare case for me to have a theme key completely different from the module name. I guess if it causes the problem.

Comment: Part of your indications were helpful, thank you too.

Comment: Great to know that.